# How can I convert a Java Desktop Application to a Applet to show it inside a my website

Tags: java, jframe, applet

I have programmed a Dice Game for a School Project.
It has four different JFrames Login, a main Game screen, a console view and a Winner "Popup".

What I want to do is deploy it onto my website. I tried converting it to a Applet but I couldn't get it too Work

Any Help/ideas are needed.

What I Have tried:
JInternalPanes and JDesktop Pane

And I was on the following link:
[Adding JFrame to JApplet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431963/adding-jframe-to-japplet?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Don't. Applets are dead.

Comment: @chrylis how can I display it on my website?

Comment: Don't, don't, don't, don't - it's a complete waste of time and there are better alternatives

Comment: whats a better alternative? @madprogrammer

Comment: @CallumStringer *"how can I display it on my website?"* - You can't and you shouldn't. Instead, either make a dedicated web app or use one of the web development frameworks

Comment: @madprogrammerokay, ill try that out, thanks for the headsup